# How can I amplify my transmitter's RF signal to open the garage from the 12th floor?

Tags: rf

I live on the 12th floor of my apartment building and the garage door is on the ground level  right below me but is obstructed by trees and a ledge. I do not have line of sight.

My garage door opener uses a 300 MHz RF signal. The exact model is the Multicode 3060 Remote Garage Door Mini Key-Chain Transmitter (see [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JINEEW)).

Is there any way I can amplify this RF signal to open the garage from the 12th floor even though I don't have line of sight?

Comment: Amazon link is bad.

Comment: Sorry, fixed link @tcrosley

Comment: Pictures of the insides might allow people to assist you better.

Comment: OK, here's some pictures of the insides: http://www.northshorecommercialdoor.com/mu30301keyri.html

Comment: And here's a useful thread about the devices, with teardowns: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/semefab/

Comment: Why do you want to open the garage door when you're 11 floors above?  Wait until you get down there on the way out.  On the way in, you're obviously already down by the garage.  Your request makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps he might want to allow a guest to park in a rain storm while he is still getting dressed and cooking the pasta.  Using an extender system of some sort to activate a remote that is located in the garage might be the most practical way to do it. There is a small possibility that a power line modem might work.

Comment: Exactly what @KalleMP said. I often have guests over and would rather buzz them into my garage since I have a tandem spot from my unit vs. going down the elevator, going outside, and opening the garage.

Comment: Joke: Attach a small parachute the the remote and then throw it off the ledge to the guest below. When they leave, drop a fishing line down then have the departing guest attach the remote and reel it back up!

Comment: I'll see your joke, and raise you one pressure (altitude) sensor.   Lower it on the fishing line and have it trigger when it gets to the first floor.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in a project then boosting your transmitter may be a good route.

If you are interested only in solving the problem in the simplest way, I would recommend you consider a different route. Can you get internet access in the garage? Using either the building's network or a wireless access point or perhaps your vehicle? If you can you can use a wifi based solution like [this](https://www.liftmaster.com/For-Homes/MyQ-Connected-Home) to open the garage door from anywhere in the world.

I am still unclear why a person would want to do that seeing as I am usually interested in the door only while I'm in there. Would you mind elaborating on your use case?

Comment: I often have guests over and would rather buzz them into my garage since I have a tandem spot from my unit vs. going down the elevator, going outside, and opening the garage. It's a community garage so I have no control over the receiver. The solution you linked I'm assuming means I need control over that? What I'm thinking of is placing my garage opener somewhere in the vicinity of the receiver and then someone wirelessly pressing the open button.

Comment: Ahh okay I misunderstood the situation a bit. Makes perfect sense now. Long shot: talk to your building manager about upgrading to a commercial wifi controlled system? Some places would consider this a good investment in attracting tenants.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best solution is to **completely replace your current transmitter /receiver**. If it is integral to the circuitry controlling the motor of the garage door opener, you can always wire the output of the new receiver across the manual pushbutton normally provided for placing on a wall inside the garage.

Actually that would work out quite well since you would then have two working receivers -- one long range, and the original one would still work from your car.  So you would not have to replace all of your current remotes (transmitters).

On [this page](http://www.gatesnfences.com/Long-Extended-Range-Transmitter.html) you will find a number of compatible transmitters and receivers with extended range from L. A. Ornamental & Rack Corp. The units are coded with 6800 code possibilities.  They claim a minimum range of 500' which is four times what you need.

One pair of transmitter/receivers (HEDDOLF EX220/HEDDOLF ER294-1K) **is said to work up to 1500 ft** (line of sight).  The ad copy says: "It **can receive signals thorough walls**, trees and over hills." So I certainly would think it would work at 120' for your situation.

And of course you can get additional transmitters for your car etc.

Comment: @axsuul You mentioned in a comment to another answer that you would like to press your remote control button remotely.  *If* you are allowed to install a second receiver in your space, then the solution in my answer should work since the output of the new receiver is essentially a button closure.  (And if you have a button in the garage controlling the opener, you could wire across that and not worry about the remote's battery running down.)

Answer (score 1):

Try a [cantenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna) or [parabolic reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WokFi) first, my experence is that those transmitters are not very directional and you might be able to directionalize them enough to work with a simple reflector

Answer (score 1):

There are basically five parameters that can improve the range of a radio link.

1. Transmit power
   At risk of destroying the remote, I would try cracking it open, googling the ICs inside and seeing if it can be run at a higher supply voltage.  Even running it a few volts higher, while staying in spec, should produce significant gains in power.
2. Transmit antenna efficiency
   This is more than I can address.
3. Receive sensitivity
   Not much to do here without redesigning the receiver.
4. Receive antenna efficiency
   I thought this was silly until I [googled it](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=garage+door+opener++antenna).  It may be worth noting the make and model of garage door opener and looking for an antenna kit like this one at Sears for Craftsman models [Garage Door Opener Extender Kit](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/part-number/41A3504/0009/139.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cse&utm_term=41A3504&sid=SPDxGPROD&gclid=CIbSnYGY18cCFdgRgQodH58Jqg).  Of course to get the most out of it, it shouldn't be mounted so there is a concrete wall or metal roof between the receive antenna and your transmitter.
5. Reduce noise, increase SNR
   Some obvious things to watch for might be fluorescent/LED lights or other electronics near the receiver, but without spectrum analyzer it could be hard to know if there is an interfering signal.

Comment: Bad idea to go around changing supply voltages without a damn good understanding of the design decisions that were made...

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic options for you to increase signal range.

1. Boost the transmit power

   Even if possible, this will be difficult since the circuitry doesn't look configurable.  It's possible that the transmitting IC has its output set by external components, but this would be uncommon.  It would take some studying...
2. Use a directional antenna on the transmitter and/or the receiver.

   In your case, there is no easy way to attach a better antenna directly to the circuitry.  You are left with using a passive reflector, such as the homebuilt parabolic reflector mentioned by @Sam.

   On the other hand, you may be able to modify the antenna at the receiver.  At 300MHz, the antenna will be less than a half-meter long.  Possibly there is simply a wire hanging from the garage door opener?  If so, try to stretch it out horizontally.  This will maximize reception from above.

   The problem is that you're trying to transmit through eleven floors of building.  Is the receiver only for your personal garage door, or is it common for many tenants?

   Its possible that you could simply extend the receiver's wire antenna to be positioned outside of the building.  Then you may be able to activate it from a window or balcony.  This is sketchy - the antenna will not work as well if you modify it.  But it may work well enough that it functions with line-of-sight, even though it's nowhere near as efficient...

Answer (score 1):

While I doubt you really need to open the garage door for yourself while still 12 floors up I'm guessing you occasionally have the need to open the door for a someone who is waiting outside, (like a guest or a frustrated spouse that miss-placed the extra remote - again).

As mentioned in a few of these replies an external receiver antenna is likely the only practical (and legal) remedy to getting the increased range you're looking for.  (Other then replacing the whole system with a higher cost extended range model.)

There are extension antennas available for some commercial brands of door openers, (see reply of mattfarley).  If there is not one available for your specific brand here is a uTube video of someone breaking into their control box and soldering an extension cable directly to the antenna point. Note that this may not be the best of ideas especially if the control box is not your property.  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smwjAOvVACY).

If you do go with the external antenna idea then instead of just putting the antenna outside the garage door you might consider trying to run the cable at least part way up the side of your building.  An ideal location might be on an object that projects away from the building giving you the improved line of site, (for example a light post or flag pole extending horizontally away from the building).  Even if you could run the antenna cable up close to your level it may be better to place the antenna only part way up since you obviously still want to operate the door while on the ground.

In an ideal case if your control box does have an external antenna connector you might even try a cable splitter (cable TV type) then use two external antennas, one near the ground and the other in view of your window.

Comment: I would rather not tamper with the receiver such as adding an antenna. Perhaps I could do the opposite and place the remote close to the receiver and then somehow wirelessly activate the remote?

Answer (score 0):

Some new motors, B&D CAD Advance and Merlin I.Q to name a couple have an optional features such as a system running a smartphone ap, you can use wifi to connect your phone to the operator, it tells you if the door is open or closed and can be operated via your phone also. I work in the industry and other than running a wire 12 floors or a bulky remote with a long antenna.. I think this is your best bet, you might also have to deal with the body cooperate if this is the main carpark for everyone else >_< Goodluck.

Answer (score -2):

Has anyone considered making an Amplifier using an Op-Amp? driving your signal through a long Antenna (Like the ones you find in old walkie talkies).

You need to amplify the signal somehow, that is for sure. and as you are using an RF transmitter already, i can't see why it is not possible to amplify a signal you already have at hand, with some external circuitry.